# jenkins pipeline with groovy, hide password of curl -u command

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline in groovy. One of the jobs is to upload the artifact to artifactory. I used variables to use curl as showed in picture and it works fine, but I don´t know how to hide user and pass on jenkins output job. I don´t know much about groovy, is this possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin ?

Comment: I will try , but can this be used from a curl comand as I´m using? curl -u user:pass ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin) along with [Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin).

Credentials will be available as an env variable, but will be masked if you try to print it out.

Exmaple

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
  sh 'curl -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD http://localhost:8080'
}
```

Comment: I will try , but can this be used from a curl comand as I´m using? curl -u user:pass ?

Comment: Yes. Check the updated example.

Comment: I understand the " withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId:" an so on, but where should I place this? in my groovy code under "node {  ?" chek my image.  I believe the example you are saying is for a regular pipeline for jenkins but not using groovy.

Comment: Just wrapping your curl command in `withCredentials` should work. Or you can check [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/declarative-examples/simple-examples/credentialsUsernamePassword.groovy)

Comment: I have modified as you suggest and it makes sense, but I´m getting this error (check 2 new images) . I´m quite lost now. those plug in are already installed on kenkins pipeline.

org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.CredentialNotFoundException: artifactory

Comment: You have to create a credential with id artifactory. Go to credentials tab on the left pane and create one.

Comment: yes that´s why I though. I created credential ID with credential plug in named "artifactory" but still unable to run this. this is error that I have and how I have it configured. Do you see anything wrong?

withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'artifactory', usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'pass')])

Comment: [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalStateException: There is no body to invoke
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:283)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsStepContext.newBodyInvoker(CpsStepContext.java:95)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.credentialsbinding.impl.BindingStep$Execution.start(BindingStep.java:118)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)